# Run .NET Console Application with logged-in user credentials

Tags: c#, sharepoint, console-application, app-config, credentials

I wrote C# based Console Application (with SharePoint Managed Client object model) and configured the credentials in app.config (hard-coded but in encrypted form) to run the application, the application is working fine.

However, now client is having the requirement to run the console application with logged-in user(windows user) credentials and this user will be given admin rights in SharePoint site.

**Scenario** - If I logged in server where Console application is hosted, then it should run with my credentials without specifying anything in app.config. If another user logged in server, where Console application is hosted, then it should run from his credentials and so on.

**Any suggestions ?**

Comment: You described an absolutely default behavior of Windows (or any other OS for that matter) - without extra steps an executable runs under the currently logged in user's credentials. As such it is unclear what exactly you having trouble with - so please [edit] post to explain.

Comment: "By default, the managed client object models authenticate users by using their Windows credentials (DefaultCredentials)" from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee535729(v%3Doffice.14). If you do not specify anything in your app.config and do not try to set credentials for your sharepoint calls it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the described scenario the behavior should be as fallows:

```
    using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("[URL]"))
    {
        Web web = context.Web;
        User user = web.CurrentUser; // current logged in user to the server
        context.Load(user);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(user.LoginName);
    }

    using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("[URL]"))
    {
        context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Login", "Password", "domain");
        Web web = context.Web;
        User user = web.CurrentUser; // user from network credentials
        context.Load(user);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(user.LoginName);
    }
```